# Entity Framework 2-way binding in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, data-binding

I have two classes - directory and file (i.e. files are children of directories). I have omitted most of the properties and the ID's and foreign key stuff for simplicity. That part is working. I wish to bind the Directories dbset to a table...and have it reflect changes.

I do my binding like this:

```
dbContext = New ScanContext
dbContext.Directories.Load
GridControl1.DataSource = (From r in dbContext.Directories Order by r.Path).ToList
```

And it works fine (including master child) -- but no changes show up unless I rebind. I have tried changing the iCollections to ObservableCollections and changing the datasource to dbcontext.directories.local.ToBindingList - all to no avail. How do I change what I ma doing so when I do something this:

```
    Using dbContext
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Directories Where 1=1")
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Files")
        dbContext.SaveChanges    
    End Using
```

...it ripples through and shows up in the display grid.

Abbreviated classes shown below:

```
Public Class Directory
    Sub New
       Me.Files = New List(Of File)
    End Sub

    Public Property Path As String
    Public Overridable Property Files As iCollection(of File)
End Class

Public Class File
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Overridable Property Directory As Directory
End Class

Public Class ScanContext
    Inherits Entity.DBContext

    Public Property Directories() As Entity.DbSet(Of Directory)
    Public Property Files() As Entity.DbSet(Of File)
End Class
```

Comment: Running raw SQL will *never* notify changes to the application. You have to use `DbSet.Add` etc.

Comment: Thanks. Good catch. I shifted to using dbContext.Directories.Remove(obj) -- but it still doesn't reflect the changes in my bound grid unless I manually rebind the control.

Comment: You have to use the `Local` list for everything.

Comment: Did that. Still no auto-update:
 GridControl1.DataSource = dbContext.Directories.Local.ToBindingList